# Core Data, iCloud and two persistence stores fail

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, persistent-storage

I have had an existing data model with a single persistent store, and all is good.

Now, following the WWDC 2012 video "Using iCloud with Core Data" (#227), I've defined two configurations in my model, "Cloud" and "Local" while keeping the original "Default". I've split my entities between "Cloud" and "Local". In my code, I add just the two corresponding persistent stores:

```
  NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
  if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:@"Cloud"
                                                            URL:[self cloudPersistentStoreURL]
                                                        options:options
                                                          error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }

  if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:@"Local"
                                                            URL:[self localPersistentStoreURL]
                                                        options:options
                                                          error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
```

These are added just fine. Later, when running the app and I try to save some initial trial data as normal, the following exception is thrown:

> NSUnderlyingException=Can't resolve how to assign objects to stores;
>   some objects may have been assigned to stores; use [[managedObject
>   objectID] persistentStore] to find out what is going where now; use
>   [managedObjectContext assignObject:toStore:] to straighten things out

I've Googled pieces of this with no hits, and Apple's troubleshooting Core Data document doesn't appear to discuss this. I have no clue what can be causing this or where to look. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have no relationships crossing from one store into another. Related entities must be located inside the same configuration.

For example you have entity `Book` configured to be stored in `Cloud` and `Author` to be stored into `Local`. Both are related. 
When you now assign an `Author` to a `Book` and save, then CoreData cannot handle the relationship and will raise the error you are seeing.

Comment: Ah I was wondering about this too - the WWDC videos don't have any relations. I do have relations that straddle stores. The exception is being raised on an entity related only to entities in a common store, but this needn't matter.